# how to generate longer random number from a short random number?

Tags: random, numbers

I have a short random number input, let's say int 0-999.

I don't know the distribution of the input. Now I want to generate a random number in range 0-99999 based on the input without changing the distribution shape.
I know there is a way to make the input to [0,1] by dividing it by 999 and then multiple 99999 to get the result. However, this method doesn't cover all the possible values, like 99999 will never get hit.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for more entropy from your random number source than there is available. This can't be done. If you're looking for a dispersion algorithm, then you should look at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think the answers you got so far work **if** your distribution is uniform.

Comment: Well, I think I asked a silly question coz I calculated something wrong. So now I believe the answer that I already has works. Thanks for reminding:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is some kind of source of randomness...

You can take two consecutive inputs and combine them:

```
input() + 1000*(input()%100)
```

Be careful though. This relies on the source having plenty of entropy, so that a given input number isn't always followed by the same subsequent input number. If your source is a PRNG designed to cycle between the numbers 0–999 in some fashion, this technique won't work.

With most production entropy sources (e.g., /dev/urandom), this should work fine. OTOH, with a production entropy source, you could fetch a random number between 0–99999 fairly directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
(input * 100) + random
```

where random is a random number between 0 and 99.

The problem is that input only specifies which 100 range to use. For instance 50 just says you will have a number between 5000 and 5100 (to keep a similar shape distribution). Which number between 5000 and 5100 to pick is up to you.